# Depth image from Kinect: Indexed image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, kinect, matlab-cvst

I am somewhat confused on how a depth image from a Kinect v1 is to be handled within MATLAB. I am using these (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30242-kinect-matlab) mex-files, to read my depth images from saved *.oni files. As a result, I get images of resolution 640x480 or 320x240. The values in the images range roughly from 0-4500.

What type of image am I dealing here with now? Reading this http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/working-with-8-bit-and-16-bit-images.html I would assume it would have to be an indexed image, because it is no RGB image and the values are not linearly scaled. On the other hand, I believe the values in the image are actual distances to Kinect's focal plane in mm and therefore have a meaning other than an index.

When I want to look at the image using

```
imshow(depthMap);
```

I only see black. I have to use something like

```
imshow(depthMap, [0 9000])
```

to actually see something. Why exactly is that? What does imshow(depthMap) do with the values?
Do you think its correct to use depthMap as it is in my algorithms, but look at it using

```
imshow(depthMap, [0 9000])
```

?

Comment: basically its scaling the image as: `double(depthMap)/9000` to convert it as intensity image in the range [0,1] of type `double`. You can also try: `imagesc(depthMap), colormap gray, axis image` to view the grayscale image.

Comment: Matlab's Image Acquisition Toolbox now includes support for the Kinect: http://www.mathworks.com/videos/using-kinect-for-windows-with-matlab-77799.html

Answer (score 2):

`depthMap` is not an indexed image, but every pixel codes the distance from the focal plane in mm, as you correctly believe.

To show such an image using `imshow`, I suggest to use auto-scaling by default, i.e. `imshow(depthMap,[])`, or use a fixed scale (as you're currently doing) if there is a useful meaning to the minimum and maximum. Turn on the colorbar to visualize the correspondence between color and depth, either via the GUI, or by calling `colorbar()`.

`imshow` with no scale argument will scale the color limits to [0 1], unless the image is of class `uint8`, where the color limits are set to [0 255]. In other words, with no scale argument, values of 0 and lower are mapped to black, values of 1 and higher are mapped to white. See also `caxis`.

Comment: if imshow with no scale argument scales to [0 1] I would assume it divides each pixel by max(depthMap(:)). Why do I only see black then?

Comment: @user1809923: What in the documentation makes you assume this? `imshow` does not do any modification of values.

Comment: Well, that is how I understood this part of your answer: "imshow with no scale argument will scale to [0 1]". I still have not really understood why I only see black if I use imshow without additional arguments.

Comment: @user1809923: ah, I see. I have fixed my answer to hopefully eliminate the misunderstanding.